# The minimal polynomial satisfied by the primitive generator

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I am trying to do the following problem that appears in Dummit and Foote book. But I have no idea how to start the problem. Can anyone please give me a hint? Thank you.

**Section 14.5, Problem #1(Page#603):** Determine the minimal polynomials satisfied by the primitive generators given in the text for the subfields of $\mathbb{Q(\zeta_{13})}$.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ll show you a trick that I use, really just a variation of what’s obvious, but organized so that you can trap careless errors. I promise you that I did this all by hand, no machine aid.

I’ll attack the “simplest” one, finding the minimal polynomial (it has to be quadratic) for $\xi=\zeta+\zeta^3+\zeta^4+\zeta^9+\zeta^{10}+\zeta^{12}$. I’m going to be consistent in rewriting this and all quantities so as to use the fact that $\zeta^{13}=1$. In particular, we have
$$
0=\zeta^6+\zeta^5+\zeta^4+\zeta^3+\zeta^2+\zeta+1+\zeta^{-1}+\zeta^{-2}+\zeta^{-3}+\zeta^{-4}+\zeta^{-5}+\zeta^{-6}\,.
$$
And then, calculating,
$$
\begin{matrix}
\xi=&\zeta^4&+\zeta^3&+\zeta&+\zeta^{-1}&+\zeta^{-3}&+\zeta^{-4}\\
\xi^2=&\zeta^8&+2\zeta^7&+2\zeta^5&+2\zeta^3&+2\zeta&+2\\
&&+\zeta^6&+2\zeta^4&+2\zeta^2&+2&+2\zeta^{-2}\\
&&&+\zeta^2&+2&+2\zeta^{-2}&+2\zeta^{-3}\\
&&&&+\zeta^{-2}&+2\zeta^{-4}&+2\zeta^{-5}\\
&&&&&+\zeta^{-6}&+2\zeta^{-7}\\
&&&&&&+\zeta^{-8}\,,
\end{matrix}
$$
in which you collect like terms, using $\zeta^8=\zeta^{-5}$ etc., to get
$$
\begin{align}
\xi^2&=3\zeta^6+3\zeta^5+2\zeta^4+2\zeta^3+3\zeta^2+2\zeta+6+2\zeta^{-1}+3\zeta^{-2}+2\zeta^{-3}+2\zeta^{-4}+3\zeta^{-5}+3\zeta^{-6}\\
&=-\zeta^4-\zeta^3-\zeta+3-\zeta^{-1}-\zeta^{-3}-\zeta^{-4}\\
&=-\xi+3\,,
\end{align}
$$
in which I subtracted $3$ times zero to go from the first line to the second. And so you see that $\xi^2+\xi-3=0$.

Comment: Thank you, Lubin.

Comment: I am having trouble with the phrase "subtracted 3 times zero" - please explain. Thank you.

Comment: I mean, the zero in the very first display: it’s the minimal polynomial for $\zeta_{13}$, written in a way that’s symmetric about $1$.

Comment: The question is to determine the minimal polynomials it seems there is more than one polynomial.

Comment: Yes, @Furdzik, I guess I avoided doing what you’d like, by saying I’d attack the “simplest” one.